# What is wrong with my music player for Android ???? It's going to CATCH in the try\catch statement every single time WHY?

Tags: android, audio, try-catch, android-mediaplayer

I'm done my Android app, just need to add some looping background music. Here is my method for playing the song

```
public void playAudio(){
    path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.music1;
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(100, 100);
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("NOTE WORKEING","NOT WORKING");
    }
}
```

It's not working....It's going to catch everytime, and I don't know why. Please help me. Music1 is an mp3 file.

Thank you

Comment: What does your Logcat print when it crashes?

Comment: look at the stacktrace and it will tell you why, we dont know why either. That path does not look correct though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your music1 file is in a Android playable Android format.

Then just use this code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.music1);
    try {  
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); 
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        mediaPlayer.start(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        Log.d("NOT WORKEING","NOT WORKING"); 
    }
```

You don't even need to call `prepare()` method. 
I tested it with an mp3 file and it works perfectly.

Comment: Definitely the simplest approach for a one-off playback of a single resource file. What if you have music1.mp3, music2.mp3, music3.mp3...etc and you want to play them in sequence?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly now....You guys are soo good at programming!

Answer (score 0):

Using `mp.setDataSource(path)` requires a valid filesystem path or URL.

In your case, `path` is a string representation of a `Uri` in which case you need to use a different approach.

Try `setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)`. You'll obviously need to provide a valid `Context` and parse your `path` variable into a `Uri`. Example...

```
mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path));
```

Also change the path to...

```
path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/music1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Squonk's answer does not work, then the problem has to do with trying to start the music file before the MediaPlayer has prepared it.  Try changing the MediaPlayer's start code to the following:

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        start();
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps, I have a good amount of experience with the MediaPlayer class and can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: The `OnPreparedListener` is only needed when using `prepareAsync(...)`. The `prepare(...)` method is synchronous so it's not possible to start playback if the call to `prepare(...)` hasn't completed or if it has failed.

Comment: Good catch! I've been doing async prepares so long I forgot :'(